# Re-use the URL of a deleted library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, url

Using a vanilla SharePoint 2013 on-premises.
Scenario: I have a - whatsoever - list, with the URL i.e. /site/subsite/list01.
For any reason, I need to remove this list, and I clear it from all recycle bins on all site levels. So the URL became obsolete (at least imho).

My question is: Can I re-use the URL for another yet to be built list? Or is this URL /site/subsite/list01 "lost forever"?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the URL once the list or library deleted completely. Only problem is if you delete the list from site but did not remove it from recyclebin then if someone try to restore the deleted list from recyclebin it will ends up with error "a list library name already exist.